# Spring MVC setup missing link

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In one interview I was asked this very simple question that how to setup a spring mvc application. I answered that putting all the jars in places and in web.xml DisptacherServlet setup and then [servlet]-servlet.xml  spring config file declaration. But the interviewer asked me that how will I ensure that all the request coming to the web appliaction will come to DispatcherServlet only and no other servlet will execute before it. So I told by setting load-on startup to 1. But he interviewer told that there is something else that need to be done to ensure and was not happy with my answer. Can you pls let me know what is that?

Answer (score 0):

Configuring the Servlet mapping will ensure that:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer should be that the servlet-mapping of DispatcherServlet must be the first ,  before all other possible servlet-mapping which may have the same url pattern as DispatcherServlet